What is the difference between と見える、そうです、ようです
If I have to translate them I can use IT SEEMS.. for all of them.
Is there any difference or nuance between them to understand which one do I have to use when I want to say "It seems that...."
If possible I would like to understand the difference between と見える and the other two.
Thank you
